# SoftLayer API: How to get hourly bare metal server preset prices for all possible locationGroupId

Tags: php, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

The hourly bare metal server Softlayer_Product_Package 200 has presets.

I'm trying to get item prices for each presets for all locations.

If I use the following query
https://$apiuser:$apikey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/200/getActivePresets.json?objectMask=mask
[id,packageId,description,name,keyName,configuration.category, configuration.price]

it only returns "standard"  prices for "locationGroupId" = null.

How can I get prices for all locations, different price for different loationGroupId value,  from "SoftLayer_Product_Package_Preset", but not only limited to the "standard" price with loationGroupId= null ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control portal does some internal processes to get the prices for the datacenter that you will choose at the moment to order a server. Unfortunately, it cannot be possible to retrieve all of the information that you want through a single rest request.

However, we can use a programming language supported by SoftLayer. You can see the languages supported by SoftLayer in:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/

I can provide the following python script, that will help you to get the prices per datacenter for each active preset configuration. This code could be improved, it's just an idea.

```
"""
Get active presets and its prices per location

This script retrieves the active presets with their prices per datacenter. 
Also it displays the information for hourly recurring fee and recurring fee.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getActivePresets
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices
http://sldn.softlayer.com/search/site/object%20mask
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Object-Filters

@License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
@Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""

# So we can talk to the SoftLayer API:
import SoftLayer
from prettytable import PrettyTable

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
API_USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'
# Declare the package id
packageId = 200
# Create a client instance
client = SoftLayer.Client(username=API_USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
# Declare an object mask to get prices and items information
objectMask = 'mask[prices[item]]'
# Declare an object mask to get pricingLocationGroup
objectMaskPrice = 'mask[pricingLocationGroup[locations]]'
try:
    # Get active presets
    activePresets = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package'].getActivePresets(id=packageId, mask=objectMask)
    for activePreset in activePresets:
        print('**************   PRESET ID: %s   **************' % activePreset['id'])
        # Configuring table's columns
        x = PrettyTable(['Locations', 'Price Id', 'Item Id', 'Item Description', 'hourlyRecurringFee', 'recurringFee'])
        x.padding_width = 1
        print('Id: %s, Description: %s, isActive: %s' % (activePreset['id'], activePreset['description'], activePreset['isActive']))
        print('        KeyName: %s, Name: %s' % (activePreset['keyName'], activePreset['name']))
        for prices in activePreset['prices']:
            print('                 Price Id: %s, Item Id: %s Item Description: %s' % (prices['id'], prices['item']['id'], prices['item']['description']))
            objectFilterItem = {'itemPrices':{'item':{'id':{'operation':prices['item']['id']}}}}
            prices = client['SoftLayer_Product_Package'].getItemPrices(id=200, filter=objectFilterItem, mask=objectMaskPrice)
            for price in prices:
                locationDisplay = ''
                recurringFee = 0
                # Verifying if the price has pricingLocationGroup 
                if 'pricingLocationGroup' in price:
                    for location in price['pricingLocationGroup']['locations']:
                        locationDisplay = locationDisplay + ' ' + location['longName']
                else:
                    locationDisplay = 'STANDARD PRICE'
                # Verifying if the price has Recurring Fee
                if 'recurringFee' in price:
                    recurringFee = price['recurringFee']
                else:
                    recurringFee = 'null'
                x.add_row([locationDisplay, price['id'], price['item']['id'], price['item']['description'], price['hourlyRecurringFee'], recurringFee])
        print(x)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print('Unable to get active presets faultCode=%s, faultString=%s' % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

I hope this can help you.

Let me know any doubt or comment about it

Answer (score 1):

I got the same values when executing SoftLayer_Product_Package::getActivePresets (I mean: "locationGroupId" = null).

But after reviewing the order configurations for fast servers, I can see that the presets are pre-established/fixed configurations and this seems to be the reason why the items prices displayed using “getActivePresets” don’t have locations to choose. These price ids with a locationGroupId = null are considered as "a standard price" and the API will internally switch the prices for the customer. But it is recommend first to execute first the verifyOrder in order to see if the wanted order is ok (the fee can vary).

For example when executing the following this request:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/200/getActivePresets.json?objectMask=mask [id,description,keyName,configuration.category, configuration.price,prices]
```

We get the pre-established prices (Package: 200, Preset: 66):

```
* Item prices: Disk Controller (NoRAID)  -- > price id: 32927
* server ("Single Intel Xeon E3-1270 v3 (4 Cores, 3.50 GHz)") --> price id: 37318
* RAM ("32 GB RAM") --> price id: 37360
* disk0 (“960 GB SSD (3 DWPD)”) --> price id: 50407
*disk1 ("960 GB SSD (3 DWPD)”) --> price id: 50407
```

Internally, API will match these prices and chosen location by the customer. 
The locations that may match with these prices are the old locations,for example: dal01, ams01, dal07 dal06, sng01, hou02, wdc01, SJC01.

But the above prices are not the only items to configure for an hourly fast server. For example for this order we need more items to configure:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder

{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server",
      "quantity": 1,
      "location": "SANJOSE",
      "packageId": 200,
      "useHourlyPricing": 1,
      "presetId": 66,
      "prices": [
        {
          "id": 37318        # Single Intel Xeon E3-1270 v3 (4 Cores, 3.50 GHz)
        },
        {
          "id": 37360        # "32 GB RAM
        },
        {
          "id": 44992        # "CentOS 7.x (64 bit)"
        },
        {
          "id": 32927        # "Non-RAID  Non-RAID"
        },
        {
          "id": 50407        # disk0 - 960 GB SSD (3 DWPD)
        },
        {
          "id": 50407        # disk1 - 960 GB SSD (3 DWPD)
        },
        {
          "id": 34183        # "0 GB Bandwidth"
        },
        {
          "id": 26737        # "100 Mbps Public & Private Network Uplinks"
        },
        {
          "id": 33483        # "Unlimited SSL VPN Users & 1 PPTP VPN User per account"
        },
        {
          "id": 34807        # "1 IP Address"
        },
        {
          "id": 25014        # "Reboot / KVM over IP"
        }
      ],
      "hardware": [
        {
          "hostname": "myhostname",
          "domain": "mydomain.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

To get these item prices, we can use the following:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/200/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[id,item[keyName,description],pricingLocationGroup[locations[id, name, longName]]]
```

In this request, we can see that some items could have “locationGroupId <> null” according to location to choose

References:

> http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices
>   http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getAllObjects
>   http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package
>   http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/Location-based-Pricing-and-You

**EDIT**

There are limited amount of Fast provision servers in each datacenter. Even if we go to the portal and choose any datacenter, there are some cases that an error is displayed after verifying the order, i.e.:

> There is currently no hardware available for package # 200 with preset
>   configuration # 66 in Frankfurt 2. Please select a different
>   datacenter.

It means that there is not enough hardware in that location for the order. It seems that the availability orders for fast provision servers are just in few Datacenters, for that reason they don’t have a specific location group. For example, if we execute the following request to know the available location group pricing, we can see that each group has more than 1 location and maybe the fast provision order is available just for one of those datacenters (no other orders will be accepted on these DCs).

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Location_Group_Pricing/getAllObjects?objectMask=mask[locations]
```

When the customers who are using FastProvision servers and cancel them, they go back into the available pool and become once again 'orderable'.

For the moment now these kind of orders are working with "standard prices".

Comment: mcruz, thanks.  I understand the order needs other items besides the ones in the preset, and softlayer internally for "locationGroupId" = null. My app displays the price to the user.  SoftLayer_Product_Package::getActivePresets only gives the "Standard" price, it won't show the exact price for each data center, the price listed to the user is not accurate for the data center he chose.   SoftLayer API SoftLayer_Product_Package::getActivePresets needs to return prices for different locations, not only the standard  "locationGroupId' = null

Comment: @mnnmountain, please see my "EDIT". I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the prices for an preset order like the portal you need to use other methods:

This method will give you the available servers, its presets(if it has), and its prices like in the portal
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package_Server/getAllObjects

But the prices are standard, In order to get the prices for a specific location  you need to use these methods: http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices or the http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItems

they will return all the prices for each location.

The getActivePresets method can help you to know what are the items in the preset, and with the other methods you can get the price for an specific location.

Regards